# I have an error while working with logback-classic in scala

Tags: scala, sbt, logback

Here is the build.sbt file where i added the logback dependency

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.6.3",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.4.4" % Test
)

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "logBack"
  )
```

Here is the logback.xml file, logBack is my project name

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="logBack" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <File>/tmp/logBack.log</File>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %r [%thread] %logger{0} %level - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %r [%thread] %logger{0} %level - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="interpretlogger" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        <appender-ref ref="Interpret"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="logBack"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

here is my scala file (logPractice)

```
import com.sun.org.slf4j.internal.LoggerFactory

object logPractice extends App{

  val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)
  logger.debug("Asif")
  logger.error("Invalid Query")
}
```

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class logPractice$ (in unnamed module @0x31dc339b) cannot access class com.sun.org.slf4j.internal.LoggerFactory (in module java.xml.crypto) because module java.xml.crypto does not export com.sun.org.slf4j.internal to unnamed module @0x31dc339b
    at logPractice$.delayedEndpoint$logPractice$1(logPractice.scala:5)
    at logPractice$delayedInit$body.apply(logPractice.scala:3)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:563)
    at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:561)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:926)
    at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
    at logPractice$.main(logPractice.scala:3)
    at logPractice.main(logPractice.scala)
```

Moreover the object of logger don not run the logger.info() and generate and error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it has been resolved by importing the library

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
```